# Rubygems now requires Ruby 1.8.7 or later?

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

I am very new to Linux and Ruby and am very interested in learning Rails development.

I have been going around in circles trying to figure out how to install Ruby and Rubygems.  I had Ruby 1.8.6 installed, but then decided that I should use RVM.

I installed Ruby 2.0.0 with RVM.  I then downloaded and tried to install Rubygems 2.0.7.  which tells me that Rubygems requires 1.8.7, but my version clearly shows I have 2.0.0.

I am using Linux Mint 15.

Someone please help this newbie.

```
james@dev1 ~/rubygems-2.0.7 $ sudo ruby setup.rb
Rubygems now requires Ruby 1.8.7 or later
james@dev1 ~/rubygems-2.0.7 $ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
james@dev1 ~/rubygems-2.0.7 $
```

Comment: Exactly how did you set up `rvm`? If you did it correctly, you shouldn't have to `sudo` for anything.

Comment: I just followed the web site's instructions for rvm. Removing sudo worked!  Dude I'm so lost with all this stuff.  I have like 30 years dev experience, most of it MS (and most recently C#/MVC).  It's just hard for me to figure out where to start.  I just know that I am sick of MS here lately and want to try something different.  Thanks!

Comment: Keep at it, you'll get there. :) In this case, `rvm` has some very specific directions on their website about installation and avoiding the use of `sudo`, so that's the trick in this case.

Comment: I have a lot of tricks to learn, it seems.

Comment: Be careful using random web pages to "help" you install things on your system. Data goes stale very quickly on the Internet but it doesn't go away, so you can find a lot of bad information. Your first stop for installing something is always the original source. RVM is very powerful and that means you need to read through the documentation a couple times to catch all the important features and caveats. Once you do it will be smooth sailing. Or at least smoother sailing.

Answer (score 1):

RVM sets up a Ruby environment for a specific user.

In this case, you configured it for your account "james". And, you evidently installed Ruby 2.0.0 on your account via `rvm`.

When you do a `sudo ruby setup.rb` you are running Ruby as root. That is, it's like logging in as root then running `ruby setup.rb` from the command line.

root doesn't have an RVM configured Ruby so it uses the system default, which is evidently version 1.8.7.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe it was using the wrong one somehow.  But not really having the Linux knowledge I obviously need, I didn't understand why.  Thanks for your explanation.